# .NET — Managing NuGet packages’ common dependencies with different versions

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I have two solutions: SolutionA and SolutionB (in separate repositories). Both solutions have dependencies on Package1, but projects under SolutionA leverage version 1.0.0 of this package, but projects under SolutionB leverages 2.0.0.

Now, a need arises to pack and publish a NuGet package of a library in SolutionB, which will be consumed in libraries in SolutionA.

As expected, I see a downgrade error when trying this. So, I decide to downgrade the version of Package1 in SolutionB to version 1.0.0. Code still compiles; there are no bad side-effects during run-time. Then, I pack and publish and try to reconsume in SolutionA **edit: At this point, I have tried reinstalling the newest version of the SolutionB NuGet package by both uninstalling it completely then reinstalling and just downgrading it directly within NuGet Package Manager (w/e it’s called..) within VS**

At this point, I **still** see a downgrade error, citing that the SolutionB dependency is leveraging a higher version, but in reality, it isn’t anymore. Why?

Halp!!

**edit: adding the error for reference. I chose Newtonsoft.Json to demonstrate. This is easy to reproduce with, really, any NuGet package with multiple versions**

> Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Newtonsoft.Json from 11.0.2
>   to 9.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a
>   different version.   TestProjectA -> TestProjectB 1.0.0 ->
>   Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.2)   TestProjectA -> Newtonsoft.Json (>=
>   9.0.1)

TestProjectA's NuGet dependencies:

[image]

TestProjectB's NuGet dependencies:

[image]

Comment: You probably need a `<bindingRedirect/>` entry in your config file. (possibly more than one). NuGet hell is no fun.  Without more info (versions of things, what the error message is, etc.) I suspect no one here will be able to help.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the suggestion. Which config file are you referring to? I'm working in .NET Standard

Comment: Sorry, can't help.  We're working against 4.x.  In traditional .NET, you can put an `<dependentAssembly>` element (with included `<assemblyIdentity>` and `<bindingRedirect>` entries) in the config file to sort out assembly binding issues.  I don't know how to do that in the Core/Standard world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that when changing the TestProjectB, you either increase the NuGet Package version or clear your local NuGet caches (`dotnet nuget locals all --clear`).

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. The older version kept getting pulled from the cache everytime. Thanks, @MartinUllrich!